# How to determine the order of AR/MA terms with acf and pacf plots in R

Tags: r, advanced-custom-fields, arima, autocorrelation

How can I identify p and q for AR/MA in R with the given acf/pacf plots without `auto.arima`?

pacf plot:

[image]

acf plot:

[image]